# Как сделать кнопку на css

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать кнопку с левой стрелкой использую только css. Прикладываю картинку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать квадратную понятно как, а вот сделать слева стрелку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Треугольники спасут мир!

[Подробнее...](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css)

```css
.block {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid green;
}
#text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div id="text">Обратный звонок</div>
</div>
```